# The POST method is not supported for this route laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I´m traying to create form to create event.

i have one resourceRoute in my laravel 7. But when i send my form, return this message:

> The POST method is not supported for this route

but how i said i have a resource route, and i call to method create.

My routes
Route::resource('calendario', 'CalendarioController');

My form:

```
div class="col-xs-12 p-5">
                <form action="{{ Request::is('calendario/*/edit') ? route('calendario.update', $event->id) : route('calendario.create') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    
                    @if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'calendario.edit')
                        @method('PUT') 
                    @endif

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="{{ isset($event) ? $event->nombre : old('nombre') }}" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Nombre del cliente">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fecha-inicio">Fecha Inicio</label>
                        <input type="text" value="{{ isset($event) ? $event->fecha_inicio : old('fecha_inicio') }}" class="form-control" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha-inicio">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fecha-inicio">Fecha Fin</label>
                        <input type="text" value="{{ isset($event) ? $event->fecha_fin : old('fecha_fin') }}" class="form-control" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha-fin">
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="{{ Request::is('calendario/*/edit')  ? 'Guardar' : 'Crear Cita' }}">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

thsi form it´s used also for edit event and in edit i can ok... I don´t understand that i´m doing wrong

Thanks you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is 100% an issue with the `Route::resource('calendario', 'CalendarioController')`

The update method accepts `put` as I can remember.

As you can see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers): put/patch

So you can change your form method to `method="put"` or your have to define your routes like this: `Route::post('path/{id}', 'CalendarioController@update')`

Comment: this form it's used for create and update for this, i'm checking mu routeName

Comment: thanks you for your reponse.but Maybe i can't explain me correctly. I don't need update. I need create. Update it's ok but store it's my problem

Comment: then you have to change this in your first line of the form: route('calendario.update', $event->id) to route('calendario.store')

Comment: If you can see all my code you can see that in my action i have any checks, but If all check are false...my route it's calendario.store. And in this point it's my problem. All this view i'm using for create and update

Comment: Did you inspect the form in google dev tools? What method and route is shown when u press submit at this point?

Comment: and method? post? Should it not be 'store'?

Comment: Ah ok, there is a create method also: did u see that: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller

Comment: There stand it accepts get method by default.

Comment: accepts method get for get view, but form should be post and route it's post

Comment: maybe a different route is triggered - can u change the route to /test-something-else/create - when this works - a different route is triggered instead of the /create route